# Dialog X/Y positioning

Tags: java, swing, position, joptionpane, jdialog

I want to display some user info relative to a mouse click.  I converted a JOptionPane into a JDialog to accomplishment this.  However, when invoking the message display, I have to pass evt.get?OnScreen() X/Y locations to get proper positioning.  I expected evt.get?() to provide the proper JFrame relative coordinates.  Obviously, there is something I am not grasping on JDialog positioning.  Enlightenment would appreciated.  Thanks ...

I have provided sample Netbeans code that demonstrates the problem.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
   public NewJFrame()
   {
      initComponents();
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
   private void initComponents()
   {
      setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter()
      {
         public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)
         {
            formMouseClicked(evt);
         }
      });

      javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
      getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
      layout.setHorizontalGroup(
         layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
      );
      layout.setVerticalGroup(
         layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
      );

      pack();
   }// </editor-fold>                        

   private static int showUserMessage(
           Component parent,
           String title,
           String text,
           int type,
           int options,
           int x,
           int y
   )
   {
      JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(text, type, options);

      JDialog optionDialog = optionPane.createDialog(parent, title);
      optionDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
      optionDialog.setLocation(x, y);
      optionDialog.setVisible(true);

      if (optionPane.getValue() == null)
      {
         return JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION;
      }

      return (int) optionPane.getValue();
   }

   private void formMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)                                  
   {                                      
      int rsp = showUserMessage(
              this,
              "TITLE",
              "MESSAGE",
              JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
              JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
              //evt.getXOnScreen(), // Positions correctly
              //evt.getYOnScreen()  // Positions correctly
              evt.getX(),
              evt.getY()
      );
      System.out.println("rsp=" + rsp);
   }                                 

   /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
      //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
      /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
       * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
       */
      try
      {
         for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels())
         {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName()))
            {
               javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
               break;
            }
         }
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
      {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } catch (InstantiationException ex)
      {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } catch (IllegalAccessException ex)
      {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex)
      {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
      //</editor-fold>

      /* Create and display the form */
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
      {
         public void run()
         {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }

   // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
   // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: I got what I wanted by changing
   optionDialog.setLocation(x, y);
to
   optionDialog.setLocation(x + parent.getX(), y + parent.getY());

Still, it seems to me that if I use event.get/Y and provide the parent JFrame, the positioning would have been relative to the JFrame rather that the screen.

Comment: I finally identified my misconception.  When I converted the JScrollPane into a JDialog, I attributed the characteristics of a JScrollPane to the JDialog, specifically, that the dialog was constrained to the surface of the parent.  I realized that this was not true and that the JDialog could be located anywhere on the screen.

Comment: *"the JDialog could be located anywhere on the screen"* So can a `JOptionPane`. It's just a little more tricky because (by default) they are modal.

Comment: BTW - be sure to add the language and GUI toolkit tags in future. Doing so would typically lead to more views than one every three days and thus result in better help faster.